# xrandr rejects 1600x900 mode

Tags: display, virtualization, display-resolution, vmware, xrandr

I'm running Ubuntu as a VMware guest.  After upgrading to Ubuntu 22 and rebooting, the resolution was off: it should be 1600x900, but this wasn't a choice.

I followed the instructions at [Screen Resolution Issue on Ubuntu VM running in VMware Workstation on Win7 host](https://askubuntu.com/questions/701457/screen-resolution-issue-on-ubuntu-vm-running-in-vmware-workstation-on-win7-host) and at [How to set the monitor to its native resolution which is not listed in the resolutions list?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19954/how-to-set-the-monitor-to-its-native-resolution-which-is-not-listed-in-the-resol) , and added the 1600x900 mode, but get errors when I try to use it, as shown below:

```
~$ cvt 1600 900
# 1600x900 59.95 Hz (CVT 1.44M9) hsync: 55.99 kHz; pclk: 118.25 MHz
Modeline "1600x900_60.00"  118.25  1600 1696 1856 2112  900 903 908 934 -hsync +vsync
~$ xrandr -q
Screen 0: minimum 16 x 16, current 1440 x 900, maximum 32767 x 32767
XWAYLAND0 connected primary 1440x900+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1440x900      59.75*+
   1152x864      59.78  
   1024x768      59.68  
   800x600       59.47  
   640x480       59.38  
   320x240       59.52  
   1280x800      59.81  
   720x480       59.71  
   640x400       59.20  
   320x200       58.96  
   1368x768      59.71  
   1280x720      59.86  
   1024x576      59.58  
   864x486       59.45  
   720x400       59.55  
   640x350       58.91  
   1600x900      59.95  
~$ xrandr --output XWAYLAND0 --mode 1600x900
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  139 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  21 (RRSetCrtcConfig)
  Value in failed request:  0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  22
  Current serial number in output stream:  22
```

I'm not sure what to do next.

(VMware tools is installed - e.g. copy and paste between guest and host works fine.)

Comment: you are using Wayland, not xorg, which is why xrandr doesn't work. In Wayland with Gnome/Mutter compositor, if an option for the resolution you want isn't found and [this link](https://davejansen.com/add-custom-resolution-and-refresh-rate-when-using-wayland-gnome/) doesn't work, you're pretty much stuck (unless you fake the monitor's EDID data or some other hacky trick)

Comment: @Esther It worked fine before I upgraded to Ubuntu 22.

Comment: from which version? Wayland only became default as of 21.04.

Comment: @Esther Yes, it was from 20.  But: If switch VMware out of full screen, then back into full screen, it works! Is there a way to avoid doing this manually?